# how to use the verb "compare"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Which is preferable as an instruction for an assignment:

> Compare the skyscrapers of NYC in terms of height, year of inauguration and number of floors!

or:

> Compare the skyscrapers of NYC **with each other**, in terms of height, year of inauguration and number of floors!

Answer (score 1):

In the firat form "with each other is implied, but reasonably clearly. For man instruction one wants to be clear and free from ambiguity to the maximum extent possible,  so the second, fuller, form, is preferable. But the first is not wrong, nor ambiguous.